# MYSQL query to retrieve comments and replies

Tags: mysql, sql, data-structures, subquery

I am having trouble writing a mysql query, I am aware I can do it via iteration, but believe it can be achieved in a single query, I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a comments table and a user table.
I am adding "reply to comment" functionality by modifying the comment table to contains the id of the comment replied to.

data structure:

```
`comments`
  (`i` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  ,`id` int (5) NOT NULL
  ,`deleted` tinyint NULL
  ,`articleId` int (5) NOT NULL
  ,`userId` VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL
  ,`comment` VARCHAR (2000) NOT NULL
  ,`replyTo` int (5) NULL
  ,`knownFrom` datetime NOT NULL
  ,`knownTo` datetime NOT NULL

'users'
  (`i` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  ,`id` VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL
  ,`deleted` tinyint NULL
  ,`name` VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL
  ,`email` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
  ,`knownFrom` datetime NOT NULL
  ,`knownTo` datetime NOT NULL
```

Currently I am retrieving comments using the below query:

```
SELECT 
c.id, c.articleId, c.userId, c.comment, c.replyTo, u.name, c.knownFrom 
FROM `comments` c 
INNER JOIN `users` u ON c.userId=u.id 
WHERE 
c.`articleId` = :articleId 
AND c.`deleted` IS NULL 
AND c.`knownTo` = '9999-12-31 23:59:59' 
AND u.`knownTo` = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
```

How do i retrieve data in this format?

```
c.id    c.articleId    c.userId    c.comment    c.replyTo    u.name    c.knownFrom
 1           1             1        comment       null       user1       date
 2           1             2         reply         1         user2       date
 3           1             3         reply         1         user4       date
 4           1             4        comment       null       user3       date
 5           1             5        comment       null       user5       date
```

Structure breakdown:

- All comments are retrieved for an article.
- Comments which are not replies are retrieved first with the
  'repliedTo' column as null.
- Replies follow the comment with the corresponding ID.

Is this possible in a single query or using sub selects?

Is this better than iteration over comments to retrieve replies?

Many thanks in advance:-) !!

Comment: What is this `AND replyTo IS NULL = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'` ? i doubt this query works?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Are you joking here?  Obviously it was included to make solving the problem harder.  After all, who wants easy rep?

Comment: Sorry that was a copy and paste error from an older query, edited and removed!